# Struggling in getting value from array with variable as index/argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I'm struggling with an issue in getting value from array with variable as an index.

I'm trying to get value from array "ok"

```
ok = {"3"=>"on", "4"=>"on", "6"=>"on", "7"=>"on"}
```

In my code (in my model):

```
@i=0;
@veh = VehicleClass.order(id: :asc)
@veh.each do |veh|
@i = veh.id;

      checkbox = ok[@i];

end
```

Interesting is that, when I try to call the array by:

```
checkbox = ok['3'] => I got the value "on"
```

in case of

```
@i=3; checkbox = ok[@i] => result NULL.
```

I was trying many options like:

```
checkbox = ok[@i]
checkbox = ok['@i']
checkbox = ok['#{@i}']
checkbox = ok['#{i}']
checkbox = ok[i]
checkbox = ok[:i]
```

Nothing works..:(

Any thoughts / suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes for interpolation

```
checkbox = ok["#{@i}"]
```

You are using single quotes that's why it's not working

or you can also use [`to_s`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Fixnum/to_s)

```
checkbox = ok[@i.to_s]
```